# Angular Material Spinner not showing, but present in DOM

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I have following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <button
            class="float-right icon-link"
            mat-icon-button>
            <i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="text-align: center">
        <audio
            controls
            controlsList="nodownload"
            >
            <source src="" />
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mat-spinner-wrapper float-left">
        <mat-spinner
            [diameter]="30"
            mode="indeterminate"
            >
        </mat-spinner>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

But the spinner is not showing even though it is present in DOM:

[image]

The spinner element can be seen in the console. but it is not displayed. I've added a style in the styles.scss

What could be going wrong?

Comment: change value="indeterminate" to mode="indeterminate"

Comment: @Buzzinga It is `mode`. Had done a typo in writing the question

Comment: just to make sure did you try changing the color of spinner ? also check z-index too

Comment: @Buzzinga tried both, nothing happening

Comment: can you share what you have in mat-spinner-wrapper and float-left ? spinner might be out of screen. try to inspect that in devtools and see where your spinner is.

Comment: @Buzzinga mat-spinner-wrapper has nothing, and float-left is bootstrap class for floating left

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the "value" attribute set. Set it to a percentage value from 0 to 100 for the spinner to show.

Comment: The mode is indeterminate, so it does not need value

Comment: Did you import the module in your module.ts?

Comment: Yes, I have imported

Answer (score 0):

try to add color attribute to it and check.

```
<mat-spinner color="accent"></mat-spinner>
```

it is possible, you might have unknowingly overwritten the css